# what is the mistake in this logic for php comparison?

Tags: php

when I give

```
 <? echo $submissiontype ?>
```

I am getting the output as

```
  PRIORITY
```

but for the below code, i am expecting the output as

```
 selected
```

but I can't get it,

```
<? if($submissiontype == 'PRIORITY') {echo 'selected';} ?>
```

what is the mistake in the above code ?

Comment: please be more specific while trying to as question.

Comment: `var_dump($submissiontype);` probably an extra space in there  you could try: `if(trim($submissiontype) == 'PRIORITY') {echo 'selected';}`

Comment: when i gave var_dump, i got the result as string(9) "PRIORITY "

Comment: see the white space at the end- that's the issue. PRIORITY=8, +1 for the space, hence 9. if you can remove it from the source that would be best, else use trim

Answer (score 3):

What if you trim `$submissionType` type first.

```
<? if(trim($submissiontype) == 'PRIORITY') {echo 'selected';} ?>
```

Often there are whitespaces that we don't account for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string compare, [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

```
if(!strcmp($submissiontype," PRIORITY")) {
echo "selected";
}
```